# Deriving the rotational Lagrangian dynamics of a quad copter

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, lagrangian-formalism, rotational-dynamics, differentiation

I am reading a paper deriving the dynamics of quadcopters. There are no cross-terms in the dynamics of a quadcopter so the translational and rotational energies can be separated. The problem is the rotational.

This means that this Lagrangian can be defined (I is the inertia tensor and e is the roll pitch yaw and $\dot{e}$ is the roll pitch yaw speeds:

$L_{rot}=\frac{1}{2}\dot{e}^TI\dot{e}$

and the Lagrangian is:

$\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{q}})-\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial q}$

The part that confuses me is when you have to take the derivative with respect to time (the last part) which gives in this context:

$\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial e}= \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial e}\dot{e}^TI\dot{e}$

This I don't know how to solve as the variable I need to differentiate with respect to already the derivative and also the book (link [here](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00923127/document)) does this:

[image]

So they define it to a Coriolis vector out of no where which I can't find this specific form, Also how can I find the contents this new vector because even if they do this I still need a way to finish the dynamics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So they define it to a Coriolis vector out of no where which I cant find this specific form

Definitions always come “out of nowhere”, meaning you can define whatever you want as you want. As long as it helps you. If you want to understand the motivation, look at classical equation in non-inertial frame:

$$
\ddot x \color{red}{- \ddot\phi\times r} \color{blue}{-2\dot\phi\times\dot x - \dot\phi\times(\dot\phi\times r)} = F/m
$$

Red term (angular acceleration term) depends on the second derivative $\ddot\phi$. Blue Coriolis and centrifugal terms do not depend on the second derivative. Now compare this to the form

$$
\color{red}{\mathbf{J} \ddot{\pmb{\eta}}}+\color{blue}{\dot{\mathbf{J}} \dot{\pmb{\eta}}-\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial}{\partial \pmb{\eta}}\left(\dot{\pmb{\eta}}^{T} \mathbf{J} \dot{\pmb{\eta}}\right)} = \pmb\tau
$$

> Also how can I find the contents this new vector because even if they do this I still need a way to finish the dynamics.

As was mentioned in @Eli's answer, the kinetic energy is $T=\frac12\pmb\omega^T\mathbf I\pmb\omega$, where $\pmb \omega$ is a pseudo-vector from “standard” $\mathbb R^3$ space. However, you want to write your Lagrangian in generalized coordinates $\pmb\eta,\dot{\pmb\eta}$. To do this, you need a map that transforms $\pmb\eta,\dot{\pmb\eta}$ to $\pmb\omega$ (in the paper you linked, they explain this and give the reference, so please take your time and read it):
$$
\pmb\omega = \begin{pmatrix}
\dot{\phi}-\dot{\psi} \sin \theta \\
\dot{\theta} \cos \phi+\dot{\psi} \cos \theta \sin \phi \\
\dot{\psi} \cos \theta \cos \phi-\dot{\theta} \sin \phi
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
-\sin \theta & 0 & 1 \\
\cos \theta \sin \phi & \cos \phi & 0 \\
\cos \theta \cos \phi & -\sin \phi & 0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
\dot{\psi}\\
\dot{\theta}\\
\dot{\phi}
\end{pmatrix} = \mathbf W\dot{\pmb\eta}
$$

Thus, the kinetic energy now can be written as $T=\frac12\dot{\pmb\eta}^T\mathbf W^T \mathbf I\mathbf W\dot{\pmb\eta} = \frac12\dot{\pmb\eta}^T\mathbf J\dot{\pmb\eta}$. (In other words, we transform the bilinear form in real space $\mathbf I$ into the bilinear form in generalized coordinate space $\mathbf J=\mathbf W^T\mathbf{IW}$)

When you are going to calculate the derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial\pmb\eta}(\dot{\pmb\eta}^T\mathbf J\dot{\pmb\eta})$, note that $\dot{\pmb\eta}$ doesn't depend on ${\pmb\eta}$, so it's only $\mathbf J$ you need to differentiate. However, $\frac{\partial\mathbf J}{\partial\pmb\eta}$ is a tensor of rank 3, so it's not easy to deal with, especially if you lack experience. So I suggest, you write the whole scalar $\dot{\pmb\eta}^T\mathbf J\dot{\pmb\eta}=f(\psi,\theta,\phi)$ as a function of euler angles and take the derivatives $\pmb\nabla_{\pmb\eta}f = (\frac{\partial f}{\partial\psi},\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta},\frac{\partial f}{\partial\phi})^T$ (again, keeping in mind that velocities $\dot\psi,\dot\theta,\dot\phi$ do not depend on $\psi,\theta,\phi$).

Comment: Can you explain how to take the derivative of a matrix so its like a function of (∂f/∂ψ,∂f/∂θ,∂f/∂ϕ)

Comment: $f=\dot{\pmb\eta}^T\mathbf J\dot{\pmb\eta}$ is not a matrix, it's a scalar, so you take derivatives as usual

Comment: So like $f'=\dot{n}^TJ'(n)\dot{n}$?

Comment: Yes. If $\dot{\pmb\eta}$ doesn't depend on the argument (which is true for components of $\pmb\eta$)

Comment: I have tried to do this but it did not work for me. In Matlab the command should be diff(I,n) right? Differentiate I with respect to n

Comment: You wouldn't be able to differentiate matrix by a vector that easily. I suggest you follow my approach and take gradient from the scalar function $f$.

Answer (score 0):

the kinetic energy is:

$$ T_{\text{rot}}=\frac 12 \mathbf \omega^T\,\mathbf I\,\mathbf \omega$$

where $~\mathbf \omega$ is the angular velocity and $~\mathbf I~$ is the diagonal constant inertia tensor of the quad copter.

you obtain the components of angular velocity vector with this equation.

$$ \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 0&-\omega_{{z}}&\omega_{{y}}
\\  \omega_{{z}}&0&-\omega_{{x}}\\  
-\omega_{{y}}&\omega_{{x}}&0\end {array} \right]
=\mathbf R^T\,\frac{d}{dt}\,\mathbf R$$

where $~\mathbf R~$ is the rotation matrix between the body system and inertial system

$$\mathbf R=\mathbf R_x(\varphi(t))\,\mathbf R_y(\vartheta(t))\,\mathbf R_z(\psi(t))$$

$\varphi~$ roll angle  $~\vartheta~$ pitch angle $~\psi~$ yow angle

you obtain

$$\mathbf\omega=\left[ \begin {array}{c} \cos \left( \vartheta  \right) \cos \left( 
\psi \right) \dot\varphi +\sin \left( \psi \right) \dot\vartheta 
\\  -\cos \left( \vartheta  \right) \sin \left( \psi
 \right) \dot\varphi +\cos \left( \psi \right) \dot\vartheta 
\\  \sin \left( \vartheta  \right) \dot\varphi +\dot\psi 
\end {array} \right] 
$$

with the generalized coordinate $~\mathbf q=[\varphi~,\vartheta~,\psi]$ you can deploy the EL equation. to consider the external torques you can add to the kinetic energy the components of the external torques

$$ T_{\text{rot}}\mapsto T_{\text{rot}}+\tau_x\,\varphi+\tau_y\,\vartheta+\tau_z\,\psi$$

---

$$\mathbf R_x(\varphi)=\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 1&0&0\\  0&\cos \left( 
\varphi  \right) &-\sin \left( \varphi  \right) \\ 0
&\sin \left( \varphi  \right) &\cos \left( \varphi  \right) 
\end {array} \right]\\
\mathbf R_y(\vartheta)= \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} \cos \left( \vartheta  \right) &0&\sin
 \left( \vartheta  \right) \\ 0&1&0
\\  -\sin \left( \vartheta  \right) &0&\cos \left( 
\vartheta  \right) \end {array} \right] \\
\mathbf R_z(\psi)=\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} \cos \left( \psi \right) &-\sin \left( 
\psi \right) &0\\ \sin \left( \psi \right) &\cos
 \left( \psi \right) &0\\ 0&0&1\end {array} \right] 
$$

**Edit**

your questions:

Eq. 1.22 is wrong

\begin{align*}
&\text{with}\\
   &\mathcal{L}  =T_{\text{rot}}\\
   &\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{\mathbf{\eta}}}\right)^T-
  \left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \mathbf{\eta}}\right)^T   =\mathbf \tau\tag 1\\\\
   &\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{\mathbf{\eta}}}\right)^T=\begin{bmatrix}
                             \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{\eta_1}} \\
                              \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{\eta_2}} \\
                              \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{\eta_3}} \\
                            \end{bmatrix}
   \\
  &\text{with}\\
  &\mathcal{L}=\mathbf{\dot{\eta}}^T\,\mathbf{J(\mathbf{\eta})}\,\mathbf{\dot{\eta}}
  =\sum_i^3\sum_j^3\,J_{ij}\,\dot{\eta}_i\,\dot{\eta}_j\\
  &\Rightarrow\\
    &\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{\mathbf{\eta}}}\right)^T=\mathbf{J}\,\mathbf{\dot{\eta}}\\\\
 \end{align*}
you obtain equation (1)
\begin{align*}
  &\frac{d}{dt}\left[\mathbf{J(\mathbf{\eta})}\,\mathbf{\dot{\eta}}\right]-\frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf \eta}\left[\mathbf{\dot{\eta}}^T\,\mathbf{J(\mathbf{\eta})}\,\mathbf{{\dot\eta}}
  \right]=\mathbf{\tau}\\ 
  &\frac{d}{dt}\left[\mathbf{J(\mathbf{\eta})}\,\mathbf{\dot{\eta}}\right]=
  \mathbf{J}\,\mathbf{\ddot{\eta}}+\dot{\mathbf{J}}\mathbf{\dot{\eta}}
  =\mathbf{J}\,\mathbf{\ddot{\eta}}+\frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf\eta}
  \left(\mathbf{J}\,\mathbf{\dot{\eta}}\right)\,\mathbf{\dot{\eta}}\\
  &\Rightarrow~\quad\text{the EOM's} \\
  &\boxed{\mathbf{J}\,\mathbf{\ddot{\eta}}+\frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf\eta}
  \left(\mathbf{J}\,\mathbf{\dot{\eta}}\right)\,\mathbf{\dot{\eta}}
  -\frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf \eta}\left[\mathbf{\dot{\eta}}^T\,\mathbf{J(\mathbf{\eta})}\,\mathbf{{\dot\eta}}
  \right]=\mathbf{\tau}~}\\\\
&\mathbf{J}\,\mathbf{\ddot{\eta}}+\mathbf{f}_c(\mathbf{\dot{\eta}}~,
\mathbf{{\eta}})=\mathbf\tau
 \end{align*}

$~\mathbf f_c~$ is only „definition“, you can name it as you want to

Comment: Can you explain the edit? You still end with the same EOM?

Comment: are you expected another EOM? If so change your equation please